# Working with Cross Context Joins in LINQ-to-SQL

Tags: c#, database, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

Initially I had written this query using LINQ-to-SQL

```
var result = from w in PatternDataContext.Windows
    join cf in PatternDataContext.ControlFocus on w.WindowId equals cf.WindowId
    join p in PatternDataContext.Patterns on cf.CFId equals p.CFId
    join r in ResultDataContext.Results on p.PatternId equals r.PatternId
    join fi in ResultDataContext.IclFileInfos on r.IclFileId equals fi.IclFileId
    join sp in sessionProfileDataContext.ServerProfiles on fi.ServerProfileId equals sp.ProfileId
    join u in infrastructure.Users on sp.UserId equals u.Id
    where w.Process.Equals(processName)
    select u.DistributedAppId;
```

And when I executed it, and saw `result` in the *QuickWatch..*, it showed this message:

> the query contains references to items defined on a different data context

On googling, I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898363/simulating-cross-context-joins-linq-c) at Stackoverflow itself, where I learned *simulating cross context joins* and as suggested there, I changed my query a bit to this:

```
var result = from w in PatternDataContext.Windows
    join cf in PatternDataContext.ControlFocus on w.WindowId equals cf.WindowId
    join p in PatternDataContext.Patterns on cf.CFId equals p.CFId
    join r in SimulateJoinResults() on p.PatternId equals r.PatternId
    join fi in SimulateJoinIclFileInfos() on r.IclFileId equals fi.IclFileId
    join sp in SimulateJoinServerProfiles() on fi.ServerProfileId equals sp.ProfileId
    join u in SimulateJoinUsers() on sp.UserId equals u.Id
    where w.Process.Equals(processName)
    select u.DistributedAppId;
```

This query is using these *SimulateXyz* methods:

```
private static IQueryable<Result> SimulateJoinResults()
{
  return from r in SessionDataProvider.Instance.ResultDataContext.Results select r;
}
private static IQueryable<IclFileInfo> SimulateJoinIclFileInfos()
{
  return from f in SessionDataProvider.Instance.ResultDataContext.IclFileInfos select f;
}
private static IQueryable<ServerProfile> SimulateJoinServerProfiles()
{
  return from sp in sessionProfileDataContext.ServerProfiles select sp;
}
private static IQueryable<User> SimulateJoinUsers()
{
  return from u in infrastructureDataContext.Users select u;
}
```

But even this approach didn't solve the problem. I'm still getting this message in *QuickWatch...*:

> the query contains references to items defined on a different data context

Any solution for this problem?  Along with the solution, I would also want to know why the problem still exists, and how exactly the new solution removes it, so that from next time I could solve such problems myself. I'm new to LINQ, by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had to do this before, and there are two ways to do it.

The first is to move all the servers into a single context.  You do this by pointing LINQ-to-SQL to a single server, then, in that server, create [linked servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28SQL.80%29.aspx) to all the other servers.   Then you just create views for any tables you're interested from the other servers, and add those views to your context.

The second is to manually do the joins yourself, by pulling in data from one context, and using just the properties you need to join into another context.  For example,

```
int[] patternIds = SessionDataProvider.Instance.ResultDataContext.Results.Select(o => o.patternId).ToArray();
var results = from p in PatternDataContext.Patterns
              where patternIds.Contains(p.PatternId)
              select p;
```

---

Though the first is easier to work with, it does have its share of problems.  The problem is that you're relying on SQL Server to be performant with linked servers, something it is notoriously bad at.  For example, consider this query:

```
var results = from p in DataContext.Patterns
              join r in DataContext.LinkedServerResults on p.PatternId equals r.PatternId
              where r.userId = 10;
```

When you enumerate this query, the following will occur *(let's call the normal and linked servers `MyServer` and `MyLinkedServer`, respectively)*

1. `MyServer` asks `MyLinkedServer` for the Results
2. `MyLinkedServer` sends the Results back to `MyServer`
3. `MyServer` takes those Results, joins them on the Patterns table, and returns only the ones with Results.userId = 10

So now the question is:  When is the filtering done - on `MyServer` or `MyLinkedServer`?  In my experience, for such a simple query, it will usually be done on `MyLinkedServer`.  However, once the query gets more complicated, you'll suddenly find that `MyServer` is requesting the *entire* Results table from `MyLinkedServer` and doing the filtering *after* the join!  This wastes bandwidth, and, if the Results tables is large enough, could turn a 50ms query into a 50 second query!

You could fix unperformant cross-server joins using stored procedures, but if you do a lot of complex cross-server joins, you may end up writing stored procedures for most of your queries, which is a lot of work and defeats part of the purpose of using L2SQL in the first place *(not having to write a lot of SQL)*.

In comparison, the following code would *always* perform the filtering on the server containing the Results table:

```
int[] patternIds = (from r in SessionDataProvider.Instance.ResultDataContext.Results
                    where r.userId = 10
                    select r.PatternId).ToArray();
var results = from p in PatternDataContext.Patterns
              where patternIds.Contains(p.PatternId)
              select p;
```

Which is best for your situation is up to your best judgement.

---

Note that there is a third potential solution which I did not mention, as it is not really a programmer-solution:  you could ask your server admins to set up a [replication task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) to copy the necessary data from `MyLinkedServer` to `MyServer` once a day/week/month.  This is *only* an option if:

- Your program can work with slightly stale data from `MyLinkedServer`
- You only need to read, never write, to `MyLinkedServer`
- The tables you need from `MyLinkedServers` are not exorbitantly huge
- You have the space/bandwidth available
- Your database admins are not stingy/lazy

Comment: Take note though, that if the patternId-array exceeds 2000 parameters, the SQL server will throw an exception at you.

Answer (score 3):

Your SimulateJoins can't work because they return `IQueryable`. Your current solution is exactly the same as your former one and that is the reason why you get the same exception. If you check the linked question again you will see that their helper methods return `IEnumerable` which is the only way to make cross context operations. As you probably already know it means that join will be performed in memory on the application server instead of the database server = it will pull all data from your partial queries and execute join as linq-to-objects.

Cross context join on database level is IMO not possible. You can have different connections, different connection strings with different servers, etc. Linq-to-sql does not handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You could work around it by "escaping from" Linq to SQL on the second context, i.e., calling for instance `.ToList()` on `ResultDataContext.Results` and `ResultDataContext.IclFileInfos` so that your query ended up looking like:

```
var result = from w in PatternDataContext.Windows
    join cf in PatternDataContext.ControlFocus on w.WindowId equals cf.WindowId
    join p in PatternDataContext.Patterns on cf.CFId equals p.CFId
    join r in ResultDataContext.Results.ToList() 
        on p.PatternId equals r.PatternId
    join fi in ResultDataContext.IclFileInfos.ToList() 
        on r.IclFileId equals fi.IclFileId
    join sp in sessionProfileDataContext.ServerProfiles on 
        fi.ServerProfileId equals sp.ProfileId
    join u in infrastructure.Users on sp.UserId equals u.Id
    where w.Process.Equals(processName)
    select u.DistributedAppId;
```

Or `AsEnumerable()` as long as you "get out" of Linq to SQL and into Linq to Objects for the "offending" context.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but as I happened to have the same problem, my solution was to pass the manually crafted T-SQL cross-server query (with linked servers) directly to the provider through the ExecuteQuery method of the first context:

```
db.ExecuteQuery(Of cTechSupportCall)(strSql).ToList
```

This just saves you from having to create a view server side, and Linq to SQL still maps the results to the proper type. This is useful when there is that one query that is just impossible to formulate in Linq.