# Is it possible to do an outer join between two different databases

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ: Join MySql and SQL Server tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256790/linq-join-mysql-and-sql-server-tables)

I don't think it's possible but is there any way you can do a join on a table in a MYSQL database to a table in SQL server?

I rather expect I'll need to make an array of data from MYSQL and programmatically use it against the data in the SQL Server but thought I'd check first!

Comment: from SQL Server create a linked server to the MySQL server. now you can just do a join,  your join will look like `FROM dbo.Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN  LinkedMySQL.DbName.SChem>TableName t2 on t1.SomeColumn = t2.SomeColumn`  notice the 4 part notation against the linked server, use `sp_addlinkedserver` to create the linked server

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256790/linq-join-mysql-and-sql-server-tables

Comment: And http://www.unityjdbc.com/doc/multiple/multiplequery.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to link your MySql database through MS SQL Server. Then access both databases through your SQL Server DataContext. Here's a couple examples of how to set up the link and docs:

http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/

http://sql-articles.com/blogs/creating-linked-server-to-mysql-from-sql-server/

> MSDN: Linking Servers With that complete, you may want to expose the
>   linked tables with either stored procedures or views so they appear to
>   be part of the SQL Server database.

Keep in mind that this approach (and any approach I can think of) won't be particularly fast. There's no magic to speed up the cost of relating data across databases and a network. It's biggest benefit is that it presents a consistent and simple view of the data to the application developer.

Taken from

[LINQ: Join MySql and SQL Server tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256790/linq-join-mysql-and-sql-server-tables)