# LINQ code to combine two database tables?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq, razor

So I have a table that I am showing on a website that gets all the information from a database via some LINQ code. The table **"db.Log"** contains a few things and a foreign key **customerId** which is linked to the **Id** in a database called **dbo.customers** *(it has Id and customerName only)* and I would like the LINQ code to combine those two so I can fill the table with the names of the customers instead of an ID which doesn't really say anything unless you know them all. Below is the current code:

**LogModelsController.cs**

```
message = (from log 
           in db.Log 
           select log);

int pageSize = 10;
int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

return View(message.OrderByDescending(i => i.timeStamp).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

**LogModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ASDMVC.Models
{
    [Table("Log")]
    public class LogModel
    {
        [Key]
        public long id { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public DateTime timeStamp { get; set; }
        public string level { get; set; }
        public int customerId { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogDBContext:DbContext
    {
        public LogDBContext() : base("MySqlConnection")
        {

        }

        public DbSet <LogModel> Log { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I'm very new to LINQ code so excuse me for that, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

### Edit: NewCustomerModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ASDMVC.Models
{
    [Table("Customers")]
    public class NewCustomerModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Customer Id")]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public CustomerDBContext() : base("MySqlConnection")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<NewCustomerModel> Customers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I think (after speaking to a friend) that this model is needed - might be completely wrong.

---

### Code after user1666620 suggestion

**LogModelsController.cs**

```
message = (from log in db.Log join customers in dbo.Customers on log.customerId equals customers.Id select log);

int pageSize = 10;
int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

return View(message.OrderByDescending(i => i.timeStamp).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

**LogModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ASDMVC.Models
{
    [Table("Log")]
    public class LogModel
    {
        [Key]
        public long id { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public DateTime timeStamp { get; set; }
        public string level { get; set; }
        public int customerId { get; set; }
        public int customerName { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogDBContext:DbContext
    {
        public LogDBContext() : base("MySqlConnection")
        {

        }

        public DbSet <LogModel> Log { get; set; }

    }
}
```

With the error:

> The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are
>   associated with different contexts.

Comment: Instead of trying to join on the fly, create a relation between the two objects. If you want customer details for each log message, the `Log` class should have a `Customer` property.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will look into this!

Comment: EF or LINQ are *NOT* a replacement for SQL - if you try to use them this way, you make more difficult. If you have to join two *entities* (there are no tables in ORMs), then there's something fishy with the entities' design

Comment: Would re-writing everything to use SQL-queries instead be a better idea? @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller:**

```
message = db.GetLogs();

int pageSize = 10;
int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
var logs = message.OrderByDescending(i => i.timeStamp).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

foreach (var log in logs)
    log.Name = Customer.Where(a => a.Value == log.customerId.ToString()).FirstOrDefault().Text;
                return PartialView("_LogPartialLayout", logs);
```

**Model:**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ASDMVC.Models
{
    [Table("Log")]
    public class LogModel
    {
        [Key]
        public long id { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public DateTime timeStamp { get; set; }
        public string level { get; set; }
        public int customerId { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogDBContext:DbContext
    {
        public LogDBContext() : base("MySqlConnection")
        {

        }

        public DbSet <LogModel> Log { get; set; }

        public IQueryable<LogModel> GetLogs()
        {
            return from log in Log
                   select log;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you:

```
var message = (from log in db.Log
               join customers in dbo.customers on log.customerid equals customers.Id
               select log);
```

In the above, there's no need to explicitly use a `where` clause as that is handled in the join.

If you want to return only specific columns, you can do something like the below:

```
var message = (from log in db.Log
               join customers in dbo.customers on log.customerid equals customers.Id
               select new { customerId = customers.Id, logId = log.id });
```

If you want to do a Join between two contexts, take a look at this workaround: [Simulating Cross Context Joins--LINQ/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898363/simulating-cross-context-joins-linq-c)

Comment: Error: The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts. I will update the post with another model that I have already written which might be needed for this to work. Give me 2 minutes.

Comment: @DanAndersson take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898363/simulating-cross-context-joins-linq-c for joins between 2 contexts.

Comment: This thread you linked actually got me very confused to be honest.